# Default Mac Web server overriding my installed XAMPP Apache server

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

My XAMPP server is setup on my Mac. Yosemite 10.10.5. Everything was ok, but out of nowhere, when I go to localhost it says It Works!, but when i go to any  localhost/directory, it's saying not found.

What seems to be happening is that it's loading mac's hidden default web server, but not the installed XAMPP because I did httpd-v and it shows Server version as the default 2.4.16 and installed last year whereas I just re-installed Xampp.

I dont know why it would be picking that up but not the XAMPP Apache server that was installed.

**UPDATE**: *Solved. I found the hidden HD>private>etc>apache2>httpdconf and change the content there to point to Xampp. More info my reply comment. The hidden httpd.conf can be opened from the terminal with open /private/etc*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes! I fixed this by accessing the original hidden httpd.conf file under HD>private>etc>apache2>httpd.conf. This file was pointing everything to the default web server. I changed the content in this file with the one that was in my Xampp folder. but I kept a backup just in case. Now localhost goes to my Xampp folder instead of Mac's hidden folder Library>WebServer>Documents. Im only worried now that I have to go back to the hidden httpd.conf file to make any changes instead of the ones stores in Xampp